# Ubuntu Studio fails to install

Tags: system-installation

I am attempting a new install of Ubuntu Studio 21.04 on a Samsung Series 5 Ultra Laptop (Intel Core i5, 8 GB ram, 500 GB hard drive). It has proper access to the internet via Wifi. Everything proceeds properly until it is in the step labelled "Contextual Processess Job" at 78% and it fails with the following error:

Installation Failed.
External command failed to finish.
Command apt install -y -no-upgrade -o
Aquire:: gpgv:Options::=ignore-time-
conflict shim-signed failed in 300
seconds
There was no output from the command

I have confirmed the validity of the downloaded iso using SHA256. and tried the install several times with the same error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks... Tom.

Comment: Some people suggest switching Secure Boot off fixes the issue. Try not to mess your Windows (if you have one) install though.

Comment: I had the identical error installing Ubunutu Studio 21.10.  Did you figure out a solution?  My error on install was exactly the same as yours.

Comment: That's strange. I found out that there was an update to the secure boot system some time after my initial problems. It was something about shim files. I would have thought that they (Ubuntu) would carry the fix forward. Anyway, turn off secure boot in the bios before installing. That may work... Tom.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment.

I took a different route. I downloaded and installed Kubuntu 20.04 LTS with no problems. I then used ubuntustudio-updater to install the A/V programs that I wanted to use. This all worked fine.

Perhaps the data that the apt-get wanted to access was not available at this time. Although, I tried the Ubuntu Studio install several times over a few days.

We are now a happy camper!

Thanks... Tom.

Answer (score 0):

I replicated this on an Acer Swift 3 Ryzen 7 4700U. I'm taking the standard install to reformat the drive completely. The problem is that Secure Boot is enabled. I entered the command line shown, and discovered that a command line prompt is being displayed related to secure boot and installing a Machine-Owner Key in the BIOS to enable drivers. You need to enter OK to continue. I stopped there since I wasn't in the installation any more.

Perhaps there are command line options so the installer will show those prompts? I didn't find any.

Alternately, it seems like you could turn off Secure Boot as a workaround.

I'm going to try KUbuntu 21.04, and then install Ubuntu Studio from there.

Comment: The KUbuntu 21.04 installer has a checkbox for Secure Boot. If you check it (and you want to watch Netflix or install proprietary drivers), provide a password (twice) to authenticate the drivers on the next boot. You'll get a cryptic prompt next boot - don't click 'continue' - click on 'enroll MOK' and follow the directions which will eventually ask for that password. After that everything seems to work as normal.